# I wanted to know how this design is done on wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, elementor

I was learning wordpress and I came to this site where  find this
[this image screen short is from a website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZaGs.png)

the screen short is from https://www.whitehatjr.com/ if you scrolled down that site you'll get that area

I was wondering if this block is a image, whenever you put your mouse over that title at the end of the the line it has a hove effect.

Is CSS applied over each section of that image or the entire thing can be created with wordpress?

Comment: Please follow these guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
You could inspect the code and try to create a similar layout (Using position absolute/relative in your example). Also, this is not an image but HTML. How to put this on WP is related to your project/theme and so on (Like any other custom HTML/PHP).

Comment: This is just html and css. the effect you are seeing is `box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(38,38,38,.2);` on hover

Answer (score 0):

This thing was created by applying css for each block.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIhoc.png . For creating something like this you need to create some custom solution for wp.